# Session timeout program in php not working

Tags: php, forms, session, session-timeout

I am learning session handling while submitting form data between multiple php pages.
For simple example, I have a php form myform.php that asks the user to enter a password and directs to myaction.php. I want to start the session before the user enter the password. If he enters the password as 1234 within one minute, it displays "valid". If he enters the password after 1 minute, it should display "Session timeout".
Here is my code that doesn't work.

myfrom.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['start'] = time();
    $_SESSION['expire'] = $_SESSION['start'] + (01 * 60);
?>

<html>
    <form nmethod="post" action="myaction.php">
    <input type="text" name="myvalue"/>
    <input type="submit" value="SignIn" name="submit1">
    </form>
</html>
```

myaction.php

```
<?php
    if ($_POST['submit1']) 
    {
        $v1 = "1234";
        $v2 = $_POST['myvalue'];
        $_SESSION['now'] = time();  
        if ($_SESSION['now'] > $_SESSION['expire']) 
        {   
             echo 'Session Timeout!';
             header('refresh:05;Location: http://localhost/myform.php');
        }
        else if(($_SESSION['now'] <= $_SESSION['expire']) && ($v1==$v2))
            echo 'Valid Password!';
       else 
            echo 'Invalid password!'; 
    }
?>
```

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Where is `session_start();` on `myaction.php` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the first thing I think you have a typo

```
 <form nmethod="post"
```

there is additional "n" before method, remove it .

the second thing you have to use start_session() whenever you want to use anything from session.